# Merge two word documents into one document

Tags: macos, ms-office

Is there a way to combine two versions of the same Word for Mac 2011 into one document?

I have multiple revisions with comments from co-authors and would like to combine the documents with comments into one document.

Note: I am not interested in the insert file method that is used to insert a document into another document, essentially combing two documents into 1. I want to "merge" two versions into 1 version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From: [Compare and merge two versions of a document](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Compare-and-merge-two-versions-of-a-document-f5059749-a797-4db7-a8fb-b3b27eb8b87e)

You can also merge two versions of the same document into one new document. In both cases, Word shows the differences with revision marks.

NOTE   You cannot merge two separate documents into one.

**Merge two versions of a document**

1. Open one of the two versions of the document that you want to merge.
2. On the **Tools** menu, click **Merge Documents**.
3. On the **Original document** pop-up menu, select one version of the document.
4. On the **Revised document** pop-up menu, browse to the other version of the document, and then click **OK**.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to use the [built in merge tool](https://support.office.com/en-US/Article/Compare-and-merge-two-versions-of-a-document-f5059749-a797-4db7-a8fb-b3b27eb8b87e)?

However, I don't know whether it goes beyond simple documents.

Comment: Thanks. I saw this but was looking in the wrong place and assumed the write up was for windows word. It's not on the review tab / section, but under tools in the MENU BAR..